# google static maps API : mobile

Tags: api, google-maps, mobile, java-me

i am using static "google  static maps API" on mobile j2me

when i use it on emulator on my PC .... it is retrieve map successfully

but when i use it with mobile it is give me the following exception:
*Illegal argument exception*

does any body have a solution for this problem

request URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=6&size=240x229&markers=color:blue|label:L|63.279591,-144.967969&sensor=false
```

Thanks

Comment: The URL looks fine.  Can you show the J2ME code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution from my TTL

in Nokia mobile http connection does not recognize "|" add URL encoded for
this symbol: "%7C" and it is should work probably